# How to increase existing partition

Tags: command-line, partitioning

Good day StackExchange Community,

I have server with 36TB attached storage with a couple of partitions created on them. One of the partitions are becoming full and I would like to increase it but it is in the middle of the list of partitions.

```
sdc       8:32   0    36T  0 disk 
  sdc1    8:33   0   8.7T  0 part 
  sdc2    8:34   0 931.3G  0 part /data/t2/olap
  sdc3    8:35   0 464.7G  0 part /data/t2/sql01mssql
  sdc4    8:36   0 186.3G  0 part /data/t2/mssql/sql07
  sdc5    8:37   0 186.3G  0 part /data/t2/da/instagram
  sdc6    8:38   0 186.3G  0 part /data/t2/da/linkedin
  sdc7    8:39   0 186.3G  0 part /data/t2/da/facebook
  sdc8    8:40   0 186.3G  0 part /data/t2/da/youtube
  sdc9    8:41   0 186.3G  0 part /data/t2/media
  sdc10   8:42   0 465.7G  0 part /data/t2/budgie
  sdc11   8:43   0 465.7G  0 part /data/t2/flash
  sdc12   8:44   0 931.3G  0 part /data/t2/footprints
  sdc13   8:45   0  93.1G  0 part /data/t2/mssql/sql02
  sdc14   8:46   0   8.7T  0 part /data/t2/online2
  sdc15   8:47   0 931.3G  0 part /data/t2/olap2
```

The partition I am trying to increase in this case is sdc10/partition 10.
I tried using parted, cfdisk and fdisk but none seems to be working

```
 1      1049kB  9500GB  9500GB  ext4         sql-t2-online
 2      9501GB  10.5TB  1000GB  ext4         sql-t2-olap
 3      10.5TB  11.0TB  499GB   ext4         sql-t2-mssql-01
 4      11.0TB  11.2TB  200GB   ext4         sql-t2-mssql-07
 5      11.2TB  11.4TB  200GB   ext4         sql-t2-instagram
 6      11.4TB  11.6TB  200GB   ext4         sql-t2-linkedin
 7      11.6TB  11.8TB  200GB   ext4         sql-t2-facebook
 8      11.8TB  12.0TB  200GB   ext4         sql-t2-youtube
 9      12.0TB  12.2TB  200GB   ext4         sql-t2-media
10      12.2TB  12.7TB  500GB   ext4         sql-t2-budgie
11      12.7TB  13.2TB  500GB   ext4         sql-t2-flash
12      13.2TB  14.2TB  1000GB  ext4         sql-t2-footprints
13      14.2TB  14.3TB  100GB   ext4         sql-t2-mssql-02
14      14.3TB  23.8TB  9500GB  ext4         sql-t2-online2
15      23.8TB  24.8TB  1000GB  ext4         sql-t2-olap2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: You've provided few specifics, we don't know what OS/release you're using, nor what problem you encountered when you tried?  (eg. was the *fs* mounted? or unmounted? etc)

Comment: If you don't have unallocated (free) space adjacent to this partitions (and it looks as if you don't have) then you can't increase the size of this partition.

Comment: You can create free space adjacent to partition 10 by shrinking an adjacent partition. To expand partition 10 the free space needs to be after  it. So if you can shrink partition 9 you will have to move and expand partition 10. If you can shrink partition 11 you will have to move partition 11 and expand partition 10